# Increment counter each time a new track is added and always select the smallest value (>=1) that is not already assigned

Tags: java, dictionary, increment

I am currently working on a train simulation project and I have a list where I save all tracks in it:

```
    private List<Track> tracks;

    public void addTrack(Track track) {
        this.tracks.add(track);
    }

    public void removeTrack(Track track) {
        if (!tracks.contains(track)) {
            this.tracks.remove(track);
        } else {
            Terminal.printError("track with id " + track.getId() + " doesn't exist.");
        }
    }
```

I want to assign every track an ID when I add it (starting at 1). Furthermore, the next free ID is always selected. For example, if the IDs 1,3,4,5 are assigned, the next ID 2 is used.

E. g.:

Add track ... -> ID: 1

Add track ... -> ID: 2

Remove track 1

Add track ... -> ID: 1

I would use a Map and every time I add a new track, increment the counter by one. However, if I remove a ID and add a new track there will be "gaps".

What is a good way to do this?

Comment: Will there be an infinite number of tracks? Or is there an upper limit of tracks?

Comment: Infinite number of tracks

Comment: The user can add as many as he likes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Saif Asif mentioned in his answer, you can use another data structure to track the id's.

BitSet is one way to go, another would be to keep track of the ids you have assigned and revoked using a TreeSet, which will keep the id's in order for you

for example

```java
public class IdTracker {

    private TreeSet<Long> available;
    private TreeSet<Long> current;

    public IdTracker() {
        this.available = new TreeSet<Long>();
        this.current = new TreeSet<Long>();
    }

    public long getNextId() {
        //Check to see if this is the first time being called, setting initial id to 1
        if (available.isEmpty() && current.isEmpty()) {
            current.add(1L);
            return 1L;
        }

        //Check to see if we have any available values to use
        if (!available.isEmpty()) {
            //Remove from available and assign to current
            Long availableId = available.first();
            available.remove(availableId);
            current.add(availableId);
            return availableId;
        }

        //There are no available id's, get the highest current id and increment
        Long highestCurrentId = current.last();
        Long nextId = highestCurrentId + 1;
        current.add(nextId);
        return nextId;
    }

    public void removeId(long id) {
        //Remove from the current (if there) and place into available
        if (current.remove(id)) {
            available.add(id);
        } else {
            //Handle your failure case
        }
    }
}
```

So in your example you would do

```
private List<Track> tracks;
private IdTracker idTracker;

public void addTrack(Track track) {
    long id = idTracker.getNextId();
    track.setId(id);
    this.tracks.add(track);
}

public void removeTrack(Track track) {
    if (tracks.contains(track)) {
        this.tracks.remove(track);
        this.idTracker.removeId(track.getId());
    } else {
        Terminal.printError("track with id " + track.getId() + " doesn't exist.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm afraid I ran into a problem regarding your IdTracker. Please have a look at your answer (I edited it).

Comment: Apparently my edit has to be approved by a trusted community member. Should I post it as a new answer?

Comment: Could I somehow use `private Map<IdTracker, Coach> coaches;`?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve with the map? I do not think you can edit my answer with a reply, however you could update your original question adding your new thing at the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

One way would be keep track of each assigned ID in another data structure, maybe BitSet, in particularly the [BitSet#nextClearBit(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#nextClearBit-int-) method

So for each time you put something in the `List<Tracks>`, you set the relative index in the BitSet and remove the when a `Track` is removed.

Something like the following

```java
BitSet b = new BitSet();
// set the bits while adding tracks
b.set(0);
b.set(1);
b.set(2);

b.clear(1); // some track gets removed, so unset the bit
System.out.println(b); // {0, 2}

System.out.println(b.nextClearBit(0)); // 1
```